# Hidden security token in word and/or pdf files?

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word

I want to know if it is possible to add some hidden data programmatically to a word and/or a pdf file.

Actually I am trying to add some security token to a file so it needs to be hidden inside.

Comment: you should edit your question to clarify your needs because if you want to hide some security token, that means it shouldn't be easily accessible. How will you use it?

Answer (score 0):

Not *that* reliable, we did add white text on white background and/or text with a tiny font size right inside a Word document. Good for short texts, in our special case.

You could use [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) or [Aspose.Pdf](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) (both commercial) to manipulate Word documents or PDF documents.

Comment: Thanks for reply but that doesn't solve problem. Actually I am trying to add some security token to it so it needs to be hidden inside.